# Hover over a div to display a ul issues with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div so when you hover it displays a ul that has clickable li links in it. So here is my code. 
 
HTML:

```
<div class="return"><a href="#">Hover</a>
    <ul class="nav">
           <li><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.return{margin-top: 10px; font-size: 25px; margin-left: 10px; background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 30px; position: absolute; text-align: center;} 
.return a{color: black;} 
.nav{font-size: 15px; position: absolute; list-style-type: none; margin-top: -25px; margin-left:100px; color: black;} 
.nav li{color: black; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; opacity:1;}
.return:hover + .nav li{opacity: 1;}
```

I created a [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/753Rt/) but the the hidden item won't show when I hover over class return. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the adjacent selector `+` here since `.nav` is the child of `.return` div:

```
.return:hover .nav li{opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Jeez thank you this is a bad day for me making stupid mistakes.

Comment: @CHASE The plus sign would mean the style applies only to `.nav li` elements that appear directly after (not *within*) `.return:hover` elements.